# Program won't connect to SQL Server unless there is no version newer than SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work for a company that is in the middle of upgrading there code to make their software work with a new version of SQL Server Express. We are currently using SQL Server 2008 with the latest version of the software with a large existing customer base.

I am a support tech and when helping with installs the only way to get the software to install and connect to the database properly is to uninstall all versions of SQL Server newer than 2008 on the machine and then install our software which is prepackaged with SQL Server 2008.

If we install this software with existing SQL Server instances newer than 2008 the program installs but upon opening it won't connect to a database. After installing SQL Server Management Studio, there is no database made upon install and if I do a backup from my machine and restore it on the new machine it still can't connect to the SQL Server.

Is there a way to install the software when the PC has a newer version of SQL Server and create the database in SQL Server Management Studio and have it connect with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: It seems like [https://serverfault.com/questions/80767/sql-server-what-are-named-and-default-instances](this question) may help you. If your app depends on your SQL Express version being installed as the default but the client already has a different version installed as the default instance, you need to point to the correct named instance. Otherwise, you could look into having them just run an installation script with the current db server and have the db run in a specific compatibility mode.

Comment: Thank you! It took a little bit for me to run across the same issue with a client. I was able to get this going by pointing to the correct instance. I appreciate the help!